# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: java, jsf, classloader

Good day everyone,

i have faced with such an issue as linkage error like this:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform(Ljavax/xml/transform/Source;Ljavax/xml/transform/Result;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/mx/loading/UnifiedClassLoader3) of the current class, org/richfaces/renderkit/TemplateEncoderRendererBase, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/transform/Transformer, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/transform/Source used in the signature
```

I have googled a lot, but all i found is the suggestion to exclude from classpath such kind of libs as xml-apis-2.9.1.jar or jaxrpc-1.1.jar. I did that, but i still have the same error.
This library is actually included into jdk 1.6 (rt.jar).

So, i did check all my included jars and it seems no kind of jars that might use target class...

Maybe i don't take in account smth? is there some magic trick??

Thanks' for help in advance.

Comment: Glad you solved it youself, but you should post that as an answer.

Comment: ok, i found how to do own answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is fixed. the strange thing was that jaxrpc-1.1.jar remained in appi.war\WEB-INF\lib, which is very weird as i exclude it from classpath and redeploy everything.

Comment: In my case i needed to remove the xml-apis-x.x.x.jar too