# java.lang.LinkageError Error in Class Loading

Tags: java, classloader

I have some problem with my JSystem/Java/Eclipse enviromment.

I get this error and i don't understand what is wrong:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of jsystem/runner/loader/ExtendsTestCaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/Document"
```

I would like know if someone have had a similar issues, I don't think my enviromment is very important for solve it, if I will understand what's happened "undergound" I hope to solve problem myself.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Solved.. I had some Jar file which contains a library, In my classpath that libaray was included twice.

Comment: Which Jar? Especify the name please

Comment: It has been solved three years ago, and now you ask me that ?? :-))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this happened for me when I included a library twice.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below URL

[java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731604/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a version of dependency, when i increased version it fixed